# drag & drop на javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Друзья, пишу небольшое приложение, пытаюсь реализовать, чтобы при наведении(drag) div-элемента на другой div-элемент, второй окрашивался. Проблема состоит в том, что не получается отследить событие именно переноса одного элемента на другой.

> HTML

```
 <div class="places">
        <!-- <p class="name">Canvas</p> -->
        <div class="place" data-id="11"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="12"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="13"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="14"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="15"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="16"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="17"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="18"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="21"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="22"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="23"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="24"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="25"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="26"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="27"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="28"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="31"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="32"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="33"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="34"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="35"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="36"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="37"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="38"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="41"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="42"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="43"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="44"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="45"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="46"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="47"></div>
        <div class="place" data-id="48"></div>
    </div>
```

> JavaScript

```
const places = document.querySelectorAll('.place');
places.forEach(place => {
    const shape = document.querySelector('.shape');
    place.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
        shape.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
            // console.log('dragstart');
            console.log(place.dataset.id);
        });
        shape.addEventListener('dragend', (event) => {
            // console.log('dragend');
            console.log(place.dataset.id);
        });
    });
```

Comment: shape - это и есть тот div, который я перетаскиваю на другой

Comment: у вас `shape` где создаётся? в `html` он вообще есть? по коду этого не видно.